# How can I make an infinity cycle creating buttons (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create button and if pressed it - creates a new but and so on (infinity cycle basically). But  it works  just one time - create only one additional button.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    rw = 0
    cl = 0
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text = 'Create  a new button')
        self.btn1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.btn1['command'] = self.new_button

    def new_button(self):
        rw = 1
        cl = 1
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text = 'Create  a new button')
        self.btn1.grid(row = rw, column = cl, sticky = W)
        rw+=1
        cl+=1

root = Tk()
root.title('King of the Kings!')
root.geometry('400x205')
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Your code (well, the original button) creates as many buttons as you want. Your logic is such that you keep stacking them in the same row and column. Are you asking why they are all going to the same row and column? Or are you asking why the new buttons don't do anything?

Comment: As Bryan said, you have an issue with `rw` and `cl` ; they should at least be `self.rw` and `self.cl`, and not reinitialized to 1 on each call to `new_button`. You are also overwriting the reference `self.btn1`; probably not what you meant. Maybe you want a list of new buttons?

Comment: I want to creat a new button at new place - fill in the whole Frame.

Comment: If you want the buttons at a new place, why are you setting `rw` and `cl` to 1 every time you call the function?

Comment: well, I am newbie so I think when I add rw+=1,cl+=1 - it will add to rw and cl variables. So each time I press a button the rw,cl will be amended accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few changes in your code. I've made `rw` and `cl` instance variables and also removed the lines `rw = 1` and `cl = 1` because every time the function is called, it creates a new button but places it directly above the first button at position (1, 1).

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.rw = 1      # Made rw and cl instance variables
        self.cl = 1      #
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text = 'Create a new button')
        self.btn1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.btn1['command'] = self.new_button

    def new_button(self):
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text = 'Create a new button')
        self.btn1.grid(row=self.rw, column=self.cl, sticky = W)
        self.rw += 1
        self.cl += 1

root = Tk()
root.title('King of the Kings!')
root.geometry('400x205')
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```